# Page method multiple callbacks

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, webmethod, pagemethods

I'm calling a page method on mouse over of an image slider to show an image from a database. The problem is I'm getting multiple callbacks. Does anyone know how to resolve this issue?

Code which I'm using for the page method:

```
var contextArray = "img";
pageMethodConcept = {
    callServerSideMethod: function (id) {
        PageMethods.GetItemLargeImage(id, pageMethodConcept.callback, pageMethodConcept.Failcallback, contextArray);

    }, callback: function (result, userContext, imagePreview) {
        //alert(result);
        if (userContext = "img") {
           //replace img source with result
            document.getElementById("displayPreviewImage").src = result;

            return false;
        }
    }, Failcallback: function (result, userContext) {
        alert("failed");
    }
}
```

Code for setting the timer:

```
var alertTimer = 0;

if (alertTimer == 100) {
    alert("time 100");
    alertTimer = setTimeout(pageMethodConcept.callServerSideMethod(this.id), 0);

}
else {
    alertTimer = setTimeout(pageMethodConcept.callServerSideMethod(this.id), 100);
    alert("time ");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you think the timer code is doing exactly?

`if (alertTimer == 100) {...`

100? What is 100?

[setTimeout and clearTimeout](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp)

You should be doing something like:

```
if (alertTimer != 0) {
    /* timeout pending */
    clearTimeout(alertTimer);
    alertTimer = ...
} else {
    /* set timeout */
    alertTimer = ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a timer and send callback only if a certain amount of time is passed from the last callback. You can do it with a counter.

Comment: hey Thanks for sugesstion i have something to show u is that what you mean by setting timer just check and see because it is not working with methods but the issue of multiple calls is resolved.

I'm editing in my question